# Binding For-Each to JQuery Accordion

Tags: jquery, foreach, knockout.js, accordion

I want to create an accordion UI using a for each loop. I have the following code so far...

HTML

```
<div id="accordion" data-bind="foreach: fixtures">
   <h3><a href="#" data-bind="text: name"></a></h3>
   <div>Information</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible: true, active: true});
```

Any clues as to where this is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put inside $(document).ready(function () {...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3", collapsible: true, active: true });
});
```

Comment: this is 100% correct, you .accordion might be called before knockout complete apply binding, which would cause problems. you should call .accordion after foreach complete