# Jquery UI and Knockout data bind

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I get the necassary informations displayed, but the original function of that accordion does not work anymore( I can not collapse the accordion anymore, unless I remove `data-bind`) :

```
 <div id="accordion" data-bind="foreach: @PageData[0]">

    <h3>Schaden: @ViewItem.Label("text: Id")</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            @ControlItem.TextArea("text: Beschreibung")
            @ViewItem.Label("text: FotoURLs")
            <div class="ui-widget photo">
                <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wien_Stefansdom_DSC02656.JPG" target="_blank">
                    <img src="~/Images/test/800px-Tower_bridge_London_Twilight_-_November_2006.jpg" width="150" height="150" data-ccuCustomEnlarge="" class="ui-corner-all">
                </a>
            </div>

        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
            <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I can not change the order of the elements otherwise jquery does not recognize it as an accordion.

What to do ?

Comment: I put the accordion inside ` $(document).ready(function () {...`, but it did not help([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182256/binding-for-each-to-jquery-accordion))

Comment: @PageData[0] ... what is that? and can you add your ko view model definition in your post as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need custom binding handlers so that jQuery and Knockout know about each other and aren't stomping on each other.

Maybe look here:
[knockout.js and jQueryUI to create an accordion menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036343/knockout-js-and-jqueryui-to-create-an-accordion-menu)